# Independence of limits of asymptotically independent processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X, Y$ are $L^1$ random variables, and $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are real valued stochastic processes with $X_t, Y_t \in L^1$ for all $t$ such that the following convergences hold:

i) $X_t \to X$, $Y_t \to Y$  a.s and in $L^1$.

ii) $E(X_t| Y_t) \to E(X)$ a.s.

iii) $E(Y_t|X_t) \to E(Y)$ a.s.

Does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title mentions asymptotic independence, but I don't see any sort of asymptotic independence condition here. For random variables $X$ and $Y$, the conditions $E(X|Y)=E(X)$ a.s. and $E(Y|X)=E(Y)$ a.s. don't imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

For your question, you can take $(X,Y)$ to be uniformly distributed on the eight values $(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (2,2), (2,-2), (-2,2), (-2,-2)$. Observing $X$ gives you information about the magnitude of $Y$, but not its sign (and vice versa). Then let $X_t=X$ and $Y_t=Y$ for all $t$.

Comment: Oh you’re right, damn.